# Returning UITableViewCell custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a subclass of `UITableViewCell` called `ReminderCell`.

`ReminderCell` has a method called `backToPlaceAnimation` that I wrote.

The problem is for example if I want to call `backToPlaceAnimation` on the first `ReminderCell` from `RemindersVC` using `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` it's not returning the correct object (it's `UITableViewCell` object and not `ReminderCell` at all).

How can I get the correct object?

Code:

```
NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:0];

ReminderCell *cell=(ReminderCell*)[self tableView:self.AroundersTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];

[cell cancelDeletion];
```

Crash log:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid index path for use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row.  Please use the category on NSIndexPath in UITableView.h if possible.`

cellForRowAtIndexPath: override:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Creating a default cell using "cellIdentifier"(NSString)
    ReminderCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[ReminderCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    //Changing "cell"'s "index" to indexPath.row
    cell.index=(int)indexPath.row; //Crashes here

    cell.textLabel.text=@"Hello";

    //Returning cell
    return cell;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Show some code on how you are getting the cells from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Are you creating your UITableView programmatically?

Comment: @DantePuglisi Updated the post, please take a look

Comment: @BlackMagic Nope, I'm using storyboard

Comment: Can you show your CellForRowAtIndexPath code? Or is your UITableView of a fixed size?

Comment: @BlackMagic Sure, updated the post

Comment: Replace `[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:0];` with `[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:0 inSection:0];`

Comment: @DantePuglisi Thank you!! That's fixed the problem

Comment: I'll make it an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:0];` with `[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:0 inSection:0];`

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `cell` as `UITableViewCell`, declare it as `ReminderCell` if you want it to be that type

Comment: Still the same problem, updated the post please take a look

Answer (score 0):

define your cell as ReminderCell

```
ReminderCell *cell = [self.AroundersTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];
```

Comment: updated, now you should be able to call [cell cancelDeletion];

Comment: Still the same problem, updated the post please take a look

Comment: is index in ReminderCell defined as Indexpath? you are sending only one value to it, indexpath consist of two values

Comment: @FS.O cell.index = indexPath;

Answer (score 0):

Your CellForRowAtIndexPath should return ReminderCell instead of UITableViewCell

So it should start with this:

```
-(ReminderCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: I can't change the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it's a delegate function

Comment: Yes you can, I have done it a lot of times. You are still returning a UITableViewCell, just a subclass of it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you showed above you're not getting the cell back from the cell for row method because the index path you're creating is incorrect.  Try using `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]` (Note: you will need to change the 0's to reflect the cell you want.